# Optimized Way of Scheduling a Differential Backup

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am working with a data warehouse with SQL Server 2012 and was wondering what would be the most optimized, automated procedure for a backup/restore strategy.

Current observations and limitations:

1) Cannot use transaction logs as it would affect my load performance - datasets are potentially huge with large transactions

2) Current plan is to do full backup every week and differential backup every day

I am not sure when DML operations will happen as it depends on my application's usage, but is there a way to just track the NUMBER of changes to a database that would trigger a differential backup? A way that would not affect performance? I do not want to be taking unnecessary differential backups.

Would Change tracking be a good solution for my scenario? Or would there be overhead involved? I do not need to know the actual data that was changed, just the fact that it was changed by a certain amount.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com would be a more suitable home for this type of question.

Comment: Daily Differential backup of a Data warehouse :S , do you actually have any uploads happening every day? I would suggest having a fullback weekly or monthly(Depending on how often you import data), and a differential backup after every data upload into your warehouse, would be an appropriate backup plan.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Are you saying I shouldn't base on MUCH my data has changed to trigger a differential backup? I feel like that would be the most optimized route. Sorry, as of now, I can only assume that uploads will happen anytime via bulk or trickle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's this ( http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/new-script-how-much-of-the-database-has-changed-since-the-last-full-backup/ ). I'm just trying to figure out what problem you're trying to solve. That is, if you find that the size is below some threshold, it will be (by definition) cheap to do.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your DWH configuration.
1. Is your DWH database partitioned? If yes, It would be easier to do the daily db backup(diff backup) for the current partition ONLY. It's much more smaller set of data to be backed up.

1. If not,  Current plan is to do full backup every week and differential backup every day is the only way since you cannot use transaction log file.
2. You could also try 3rd party disk (block) level backup software (i.e. Doubletake)....

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a mistaken notion of what a differential backup is. Don't worry; it's common. 
When you say things like "track the number of changes to a database that would trigger a differential backup", it implies that you think that a differential backup gets all of the changes since the latest full or differential.

However, a differential backup gets all of the data that has changed since the last full backup only. So, you'd expect the size of subsequent differential backups to get larger and larger. For example, let's say you take a full backup on Sunday and a differential backup every other day. You'd get something like:

- Monday: All of the data changed since Sunday's backup.
- Tuesday: All of the data changed since Sunday's backup (*including Monday's data*)
- Wednesday: All of the data changed since Sunday's backup (*including Tuesday's data*)
- etc

Additionally, you'd only ever restore at most one differential backup if/when you need to restore your database. For instance, if your database crashed on right before Thursday's backup, you'd restore your last full backup (from Sunday in my example), then Wednesday's differential, and you're done.

As for when to schedule it, that's typically dictated by the rhythm of your business. For instance, you might decide to take a backup just before you kick off your ETL or just after. Doing it during doesn't make much sense as you'd have an inconsistent (with respect to your ETL process) database if you ever need to restore it.

Comment: I do understand what a differential backup is. As you said, "a differential backup gets all of the data that has changed since the last full backup only". But is there a way to find the size of "all the data that has changed" to pre-compute if a differential backup is worth taking? I want to only take a differential backup when the size of the changed data has reached a certain threshold. This would avoid relying on a time-based backup. Is that a better way to think about it?